# Inline-flex is adding extra vertical space to elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I cobbled together a simple material based switch class that uses flex for spacing. Everything works well but, I'm getting some unexpected spacing when I made some layout variants.

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/philmayfield/pen/MepwKv?editors=1100)

```
See codepen example
```

As you can see in the example, the column on the left has more vertical spacing than the column on the right. It just doesnt make sense to me because all I've done is rearranged the spans.

I know it has to do with being inlined as switching to regular flex fixes the problem.  But the normal tricks for inlined spacing like font-size: 0 and line-height 1 dont seem to make any difference.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Rather than post your code on an external site (which could go down), please include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) inline, preferably in the form of a [Stack Snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a height of 10px to

```
.pv-switch__switch
```

[Example Pen](http://codepen.io/nirmalyaghosh/pen/dXvwae?editors=1100)